# Filesize monitoring powershell script safe to run against a multiuser Access 2003 database?

Tags: powershell, directory, microsoft-access, read-only

I'm try to monitor the size of an [MS Access Database file which corrupts when the size reaches 2GB](https://superuser.com/questions/460750/software-utility-to-send-an-email-when-a-files-size-starts-getting-too-big).

I found the following [powershell script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/candede/archive/2010/01/14/monitor-file-size.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) which monitors the size of a file, and then runs a command.

The script uses `(Get-ChildItem $FilePath).length` to determine the size of the file being monitored.  While I'd like to assume doing this is only a read operation, the fact that it will be monitoring the size of a multi-user MS Access database doesn't really leave room for assuming just a read-operation, so I thought I would ask some more experienced Powershell users if that is the case.

I'm using Powershell 2 as this is shells $Host.Version [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed):

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

And for convenience here is the full text of the powershell script:

```
function Test-FileSizeUntil
{

  <#

.Synopsis
    Checks the file size of a given file until it reaches the specified size and creates an action
.Description
    Controls the size of a given file on user-specified intervals; and creates an action when the file size is equal or greater than the given size
.Parameter FilePath
    Path of the file that will be monitored
.Parameter Size
    File size is monitored against this value. When file size is equal or greater than this value, user-specified action is triggered
.Parameter ScriptString
    Specifies the action commands to run. Enclose the commands in double quotes ( " " ) to create a script string
.Parameter Interval
    The wait interval between the executions of the function. The value of this parameter is  in second and default value is 30 seconds
.Parameter AsJob
    Creates a background job for the cmdlet and echoes the jobID
.Example
Test-FileSizeUntil -FilePath C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex091112.log -Size 500KB -ScriptString "c:\dosomething.exe"
.Example
Test-FileSizeUntil c:\test.txt 10MB -ScriptString "Start-Job -ScriptBlock { do something }"
You can omit -FilePath and -Size parameters and call the function as you can see above
.Example
Test-FileSizeUntil c:\test.txt -Size 1GB -Interval 3600 -AsJob $true -ScriptString "do something"
Wait interval between executions is one hour and function is called as a background job
.Link
    http://blogs.msdn.com/candede
.Notes
    Author: Can Dedeoglu
#>

  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position = 0)]
    [string[]]$FilePath
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position = 1)]
    [int]$Size
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$ScriptString
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [int]$Interval = 30
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [bool]$AsJob = $false
  )

  function control
  {
    function subControl
    {
      while ((Get-ChildItem $FilePath).length -le $Size)
      {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $Interval
        subControl
      }
    } # end function subControl

    subControl

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create($ScriptString))

  } # end function control

  if (!$AsJob)
  {
    if ((Test-Path $FilePath))
    {
      control
    } #end if Test-Path

    else { "File does not exist!" }

  } # end if AsJob

  else
  {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create(". c:\ps\library\Test-FileSizeUntil.ps1; Test-FileSizeUntil -FilePath $FilePath -Size $Size -ScriptString `"$ScriptString`" -Interval $Interval"))
  }

} # end function Test-FileSize
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, I don't have the answer, but I'll tell you how you can answer this yourself. Run the script against a known file on your own machine. Use Process Monitor from Sysinternals and see what operations are called against the file.

*I'd do it myself and answer your question directly, but I'd have to play around with my PS security settings - which I don't have time to do because I have a meeting in 5 minutes and need coffee first. Plus, you'll learn several things and also build character :-)*